# What should be the column title in a grid which shows checkboxes, where sorting is enabled?

Tags: tables, terminology, grid

I am looking for a title for the checkboxes where sorting is enabled for that particular column. Since they're checkboxes, I'm not sure what the title could be since there isn't any descriptive factor to them. I've attached an image below:

[image: Title description]

Is there a proper UX term for the title on a nondescript column?

Comment: in your case sort option will differentiate between checked and unchecked ? or sort the rows based on some function ( name, size, date, etc )?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a common naming convention for this but you could use this space for "Select/deselect all" checkbox. This is somewhat usual pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest that the column have no label. There's usually no need to label everything in a UI. and you don't want that column header cell to be significantly wider than the contents of the column (checkboxes).

But if you want to sort by that column you'll need something there. You could provide just the sorting icon that you have in the other column headers.

*By the way, you might consider changing the "both up and down arrows" icons to "up" or "down" arrows to indicate how the table is sorted. (Like this screenclip.)*

[image]